# How to animate a single SVG Polygon Point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, velocity.js

How do i animate (move) a single polygon point within a SVG? If possible, using velocity.js.

Thanks for your help!

```html
<p>From...</p>

<svg height="250" width="500">
  <polygon points="0,0 200,0 200,200 00,200" style="fill:green" />
</svg>

<p>to...</p>
<svg height="250" width="500">
  <polygon points="0,0 300,0 200,200 00,200" style="fill:blue" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this suites you?

```html
<svg height="250" width="500">
  <polygon points="0,0 200,0 200,200 00,200" style="fill:blue">
    <animate begin="shape.click" id="animation-to-click" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="points" dur="500ms"  to="0,0 300,0 200,200 00,200" />
  </polygon>
</svg>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="document.getElementById('animation-to-click').beginElement()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the effect i've been looking for. It's just that i'm using this animation inside a javascript queue, so i would hope for a solution using velocity.js.

Comment: may be you can do it with javascript just and append it to the queue?

Answer (score 4):

Since the `<animate>` tag will be deprecated soon, here is an alternative with d3.js.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="250" width="500">
  <polygon id="my-polygon" points="0,0 200,0 200,200 00,200" fill="blue" />
</svg>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="transformPolygon()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function transformPolygon() {
    var myPolygon = d3.select(document.getElementById('my-polygon'))
    myPolygon
      .transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .ease("elastic")
      .attr('fill','green')
      .attr('points','0,0 300,0 200,200 00,200')
  }    
</script>
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Thanks @Peteroid